# Android Map API Key testing in signed app

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3

If I have the release key for Android Map API in my app which was generated using the signing certificate SHA-1 fingerprint and app package name.

How can the map view be tested using this key? We tried generating signed APK and running it on the device but the map was not showing. Is there any way to test this key before publishing the app on the Play Store?

Comment: You always can publish your app in Internal or Closed group of testers. Google documentation here: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en

Comment: @MrVasilev that is an option but there is no way to test a release key without publishing the app on the Google Play Store?

Comment: Did you try it? To be honest I have never tried it, but I am curious about the result :)

Comment: I tried and was unable to open the map.

Comment: Is there any logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a separate `google_maps_api.xml` for release apk.
go to project

`MyApplication -> app -> src -> release -> res -> values -> google_maps_api.xml`

you will find
  `<string name="google_maps_key" templateMergeStrategy="preserve" translatable="false">YOUR_KEY_HERE</string>`

replace `YOUR_KEY_HERE` with your release key

Answer (score 1):

Even if you add release key as suggested by @sudeep, you won't be able to see map in production. It is because Google has introduced a billing system for signed APK's. You'll get $200 worth of free requests per month. To enable billing follow this link https://console.cloud.google.com/billing and enable billing account. After enabling billing go to this link https://console.cloud.google.com/billing/projects. You'll see your projects listed; click <kbd>more-options</kbd> (three dots) located at the far-right end of the project and click on <kbd>change billing</kbd> then follow steps to add billing to your project.

For further reading: https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing/sheet/

Comment: Agreed, the billing was activated as well.